# Python - Comparing entire data frames gives different result than single elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am comparing two dataframes' columns and I am getting different result than while comparing elements separately. This applies to comparing "None".

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = ["a", None, None, "b"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = ["a", None, "c", "d"]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
print(df1[0] != df2[0]) #[1] is True, why ??
print(df1[0][1] != df2[0][1]) #[1] here it is False
print( None != None ) #this is False
```

Is this "None" somehow strangely converted while comparing dataframes ?

EDIT: I have found this https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20442 but it does not give my any clear outcome... Is it feature? bug? will be fixed or not?

Comment: It's not a bug. Please read my answer, you misunderstood the data frame structure. Comparing the ```None``` values, ```df1[0][1] == df2[0][1]``` returns ```True```. You could use ```eq()``` but it has nothing to do with your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that None values in DataFrames are treated as NA values and when you focus on a single element they are considered as regular None values. `df1.isna()` shows this.

Answer (score 1):

You treat a data frame as a one-dimensional array, well it's not. When you print `df1` you get the following output:

```
      0
0     a
1  None
2  None
3     b
```

`df1` refers to your object. `df1[0]` refers to your first set of data

```
list(df1[0]) == ['a', None, None, 'b']
list(df2[0]) == ["a", None, "c", "d"]
```

From the above we can simply assume that:

```
df1[0][1] == None
df2[0][1] == None
```

That's why your second `print` is false. `None != None` is indeed `False`.
Although you initialize your data frames with one-dimensional arrays, pandas creates objects that ready to use more complex sets of data.

Comment: I am not suprised that None != None is False. I am suprised that None != None is True when I compare entire data frames.
But @rolalaw answered that while comparing data frames None is treated as NaN. And Nan != Nan gives True